# How to redirect a line fields to vars?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following output from a command:

```
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  3.032 ms
 2  172.26.0.15 (41.226.22.21)  53.825 ms
 3  172.26.0.13 (172.26.0.13)  57.146 ms
 4  193.95.19.137 (193.95.19.137)  60.792 ms
 5  193.95.96.69 (193.95.96.69)  65.873 ms
```

I want to redirect the fields of each line to the variables `nbr`, `host`, `ip` and `time`

I read all lines with:

```
while read LINE; do
    echo $LINE #How to redirect the line fields to vars
done < <(traceroute yahoo.fr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ex:

```
while read _ ip ip2 ms _; do
    echo "$ip $ms ms"
done < <(traceroute yahoo.fr)
```

Where `_` is a placeholder variable.

To strip out the parentheses like in your comment :

```
% x='(127.0.0.1)'
% echo ${x//[)(]/}                                        
127.0.0.1
```

this is bash *parameter expansion*

Comment: how to extract the `ip2` from the `()` ?

Comment: One way to eliminate the parens is to use `IFS="$IFS()"`

Comment: @GillesQuenot The default IFS is three characters longs: space, tab, newline.  We can add to it as we please.  By the way, the change to IFS can be made local: `while IFS="$IFS()" read a ip ip2 ms b; do ....`